# Find the remainder of $a^2-3a+11$ knowing that the remainder of dividing $a$ by $18$ is $5$.

Tags: divisibility, solution-verification

I'd like to check if what I did here is ok just in case.

I'm asked to find the remainder of $a^2-3a+11$ knowing that the remainder of dividing $a$ by $18$ is $5$.

What I did:

The problem states that $a=18q+5$ for some $q$, follows that $$a^2-3a+11 = (18q+5)²-3(18q+5)+11 \\  = 18^2q^2+(10)(18)q-3(18)q+21 \\ = 18^2q^2+(7)(18)q+21
\\=18(18q^2+7q)+21$$.

Could I say that the remainder is $21$?. I'm unsure why, but I have doubts about the last step I made.

Comment: Can you use modulos? Using them the algebra is much simpler to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The remainder must be smaller than the divisor.

> $$18(18q^2+7q) + 21 = 18(18q^2+7q) + 18 + 3 = 18(18q^2+7q+1) + 3$$

Comment: Oh, then I factor a $18$ out from the $21$?

Comment: @Dante Exactly.

Comment: Thanks, it really looked like I was missing something.

Comment: @Dante No problem. My pleasure.